# Using dagger-injected objects in attachBaseContext

Tags: android, dagger-2

I need to access my `SharedPreferences` instance in the `attachBaseContext` of my activity (so I can set the locale there), but the injected `SharedPreferences` instance is not available there as the injection is happening in the `onCreate` method, which is running after the `attachBaseContext` call. I am using dagger2 for dependency injection.

Any idea how I can avoid creating a new `SharedPreferences` instance?

EDIT:

Ok, so I think the problem is that I am trying to use dagger too much, I think in this case it is simply not suitable. In the `attachBaseContext` of each activity I have to update the locale, and I extracted this updating logic to a `LocaleManager` which needs access to the `SharedPreferences` instance and the `Context` that I get in `attachBaseContext`. The `SharedPreferences` instance is already in the `AppModule`, but I still cannot `@Inject` it to the activities before the `attachBaseContext` call, as the activity`s injections happen after `attachBaseContext`.

Comment: Why don't you try initiate dagger2 components in class extending Application? than in Activity?

Comment: Yeah, I cannot come up with any other solution, I`ll try, thanks!

Comment: Hi can u please help my friend on the same problem, please check the link once https://stackoverflow.com/q/53277662/3946958

Comment: Struggled with the very same problem. How have you finally solved it?

Comment: I ended up creating the SharedPreferences instance manually, without dagger @LeoDroidcoder

Comment: Yeah, the same here. Seems it is the only way

Answer (score 0):

*You can inject like this:*

```
    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface PreferencesProvider {
    
        fun getPreferences(): Preferences
    }
    
    abstract class BaseActivity ... {
        private lateinit var preferences: Preferences

        override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
           initPreferences(newBase)
           super.attachBaseContext(ContextLocaleWrapper.wrap(newBase,preferences.getLanguage()))
        }

        private fun initPreferences(context: Context) {
            preferences = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                context.applicationContext,
                PreferencesProvider::class.java
            ).getPreferences()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as you can access your `Component` you could add a [provision method](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html)

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(myActivity: MyActivity)

    fun sharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences

    ...
}
```

and then access your `SharedPreferences` directly via the `Component`:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val sharedPreferences = component.sharedPreferences()
        ...
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        component.inject(this)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` implementation and this way I am not creating any components. The ApplicationComponent is the only one I have, so this would result in moving the `SharedPreferences` to app level, but I am gonna look into that solution

Comment: In this case, the call to `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` creates a component, the (generated) `MyActivitySubcomponent`. Activity scoping your `SharedPreferences` would therefore not help you with "avoiding new instances". And the answer above, even with the mentioned `dagger.android` package, should be an option. Besides refactoring your logic.

Comment: Hi can u please help my friend on the same problem, please check the link once https://stackoverflow.com/q/53277662/3946958

Comment: Wont work because injecting at onCreate have to be called first but attachBaseContext called before onCreate so you'll have NullPointer