# How to access injected properties in attachBaseContext using Hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

For the sake of changing application's default `Locale`, I have to get access of my `WrapContext` class in `attachBaseContext` method inside the **Activity**:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var wrapper: WrapContext

    .
    .
    .

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(wrapper.setLocale(newBase!!))
    }
}
```

But as you can imagine I get `nullPointerException` because the field is injected after `attachBaseContext` is called.

Here is the **WrapContext** class:

```
@Singleton
class WrapContext @Inject constructor() {

    fun setLocale(context: Context): Context {
        return setLocale(context, language)
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I also tried to inject **WrapContext** inside **MyApp** class so the field should be initialized when calling it inside **Activity**.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application() {
    @Inject lateinit var wrapper: WrapContext
}
```

`attachBaseContext` inside activity:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext((applicationContext as MyApp).wrapper.setLocale(newBase!!))
}
```

But I still get the same error. I debugged the code and I found that `applicationContext` is **Null** in the method.

I searched online and I found the same issue someone had with `dagger` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716906/using-dagger-injected-objects-in-attachbasecontext). But there is no accepted answer which can maybe give me some sights to do it in `hilt`.

Is there a way to get this `WrapContext` class in the `attachBaseContext` method inside activity?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use an [entry point](https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points) to obtain dependencies from `ApplicationComponent` as soon as you have a `Context` attached to your application.  Fortunately, such a context is passed into `attachBaseContext`:

```kotlin
    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
    interface WrapperEntryPoint {
        val wrapper: WrapContext
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val wrapper = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(newBase, WrapperEntryPoint::class).wrapper
        super.attachBaseContext(wrapper.setLocale(newBase))
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know about this entry point. Easy and fine solution. Tnx

Comment: This did not work for me since `context.getApplicationContext()` is NULL in the `Application#attachBaseContext()` method. But it did work in `Activity` classes.